# Cannot Get DynamicSalt value to input into mysql correctly

Tags: php, mysql

**HTML:**

```
            <form method="post" id="NewUserRegistration" action="inc/q/addNewUser.php">
                Username: <input type="text" name="userName" /> <br />
                Password: <input type="password" name="userPass" /> <br />
                Email: <input type="text" name="userEmail" /> <br /> 
                <input type="submit" name="submit" />
            </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
#INSERT new (Requester)

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Error , check your server connection.");
mysql_select_db("thedbname");

//Get data in local variable
if(!empty($_POST['userName']))
    $newRequesterUserName=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userName']);

if(!empty($_POST['userPass']))
#secure pass
$escapedInputtedPass=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass']);
$dynamSalt = mt_rand(); 
$SaltyPass = hash('sha512',$dynamSalt.$escapedInputtedPass);

if(!empty($_POST['userEmail']))
    $newRequesterEmail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userEmail']); 

// check for null values
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$query="INSERT INTO User (uUName, uUPass, uEmail, dynamSalt) values('$newRequesterUserName', '$SaltyPass', '$newRequesterEmail', '$dynamSalt')";
mysql_query($query)  or die(mysql_error());
    echo 'Registered!';
}

?>
```

No matter how many times I register successfully the `uUName` and `uUPass` insert fine into the database. But the `dynamSalt` always enters in with value: `32767`

Why doesn't it have the value it generates everytime this script is accessed? I tried outputting the value of `$dynamSalt` during the echo at the end with registered and it outputs a numerical value like `1939509953`  -- always 10 integers [0-9] . The database field type is INT[10] ...

Anyone?

Comment: 32767 is the maximum range of a signed SMALLINT field so my guess is that your problem lies in your database field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mt_rand()` uses the c-library rand(), which, if uninitialized, uses the seed 1.

Try opening and reading from  `/dev/urandom/` instead (c.f. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php#83655)

It is more secure and uses the hosts internal state which is changing, so that your output does not repeat.